# Network Manager messes up resolv.conf

Tags: vpn, debian-bullseye

I'm struggling to get network-manager to work correctly - this is on Debian 11. I have a static IP address for my NIC, but I have recently added VPN, which works fine. The problem is, it messes up `/etc/resolv.conf`; before, I had this:

```
# cat /etc/resolv.conf
# Generated by NetworkManager
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
nameserver 192.168.0.1
```

As part of the VPN setup, I have specified `nameserver 192.168.50.9` and `search some.domain`; what I expected was that `resolv.conf` would be replaced, so that I would use the company's DNS when I am on VPN - however, what happens, is that nm simply jams it all into the same file, something like this:

```
# Generated by NetworkManager
search some.domain
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 192.168.50.9
nameserver 8.8.4.4
# NOTE: the libc resolver may not support more than 3 nameservers.
# The nameservers listed below may not be recognized.
nameserver 192.168.0.1
```

The problem with that is that the resolver never uses anything but the first nameserver - when I search for a server known to the company DNS, this happens:

```
# host -d vogon
Trying "vogon.some.domain"
Trying "vogon"
Host vogon not found: 3(NXDOMAIN)
Received 98 bytes from 8.8.8.8#53 in 20 ms
```

As far as the resolver is concerned, the first nameserver worked fine - it returned a result - so it never goes on to the second one.

So, the question is: How do I set this up so Network Manager does the right thing, and simply replaces my resolv.conf with what I specified for the VPN connection, and then reverts it when the VPN is disconnected?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using the *systemd-resolved* service (start it and NM will automatically use it), which keeps track of nameservers per-interface. For example, if the VPN interface has "some.domain" as its DNS search suffix, queries for "vogon.some.domain" will use nameservers associated with that interface.

Additionally, whenever NetworkManager brings up the VPN it will configure the nameservers with the 'DefaultRoute' flag in systemd-resolved, making it use only the nameservers associated with the VPN interface for all queries.

(Without using systemd-resolved, configuring the VPN profile to have `~.` among the DNS search domains should in theory achieve the same thing in NM directly, but I haven't tested that yet.)